# How can I iterate over android.graphics.Path segments?

Tags: java, android, path, awt, curve

I have an android `Path` object (created from text: `paint.getTextPath(someString, 0, someString.length(), 0f, 0f, myPathObject);`)

How can I iterate over path object segments ("move to", "line to", "quad to", etc...) like with `PathIterator` in awt?

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I wanted it to have the answer
Look at `android.graphics.PathMeasure` API  1

```
  float[] tmpPos = new float[2];
  float[] tmpTan = new float[2];
  PathMeasure measure = new PathMeasure();
  measure.setPath(path, true);
  do {
   float dist = measure.getLength();
   for (float p = 0; p < dist; p += 1) {
     measure.getPosTan(p, tmpPos, tmpTan);
     float x = tmpPos[0], y = tmpPos[1];
     float nx = tmpTan[0], ny = tmpTan[1];
     // do your own stuff
    }
 } while (measure.nextContour());
```